# Add an element in multidimentional array PHP based CSV Parsing

Tags: php

I have csv, with a lot of column,

```
+---------+------------------+
|   NAME  |  ADDRESS         |
+---------+------------------+
|   JOHN  |  ADDRESS  1      |
|   MARY  |  ADDRESS  2      |
+---------+------------------+
```

And this one will be uploaded to the web app. My question is, I want to store the name of file in additional column (last column in each row.)

```
+---------+------------------+-------------+
|   NAME  |  ADDRESS         |  NAME FILE  |
+---------+------------------+-------------|
|   JOHN  |  ADDRESS  1      |    MAIN.CSV |
|   MARY  |  ADDRESS  2      |    MAIN.CSV |
+---------+------------------+-------------+
```

This is my code :

```
    $csv = $this->input->post('path'); //PATH CSV
    $nama_file = $this->input->post('nama'); // NAME OF FILE

    $tryOne = array();

    if (file_exists($csv)) {
        $file = fopen($csv, 'r'); // r flag is for readonly mode
        fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
        while (( $line = fgetcsv($file) ) !== false) { // if line exists
            $tryOne[] = $line; // add to array      

        }
        fclose($file);
    }
```

THE RESULT LIKE THIS

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => JOHN
        [1] => ADDRESS 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => MARY
        [1] => ADDRESS 2
    )
)
```

Any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code... I am considering you are getting filename in $nama_file variable.

```
$csv = $this->input->post('path'); //PATH CSV
    $nama_file = $this->input->post('nama'); // NAME OF FILE

    $tryOne = array();

    if (file_exists($csv)) {
        $file = fopen($csv, 'r'); // r flag is for readonly mode
        fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
        while (( $line = fgetcsv($file) ) !== false) { // if line exists
            array_push($line, $nama_file);
            $tryOne[] = $line; // add to array      

        }
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$line` is and array so you can append the filename to it.

```
while (( $line = fgetcsv($file) ) !== false) {
    $line[] = $nama_file;
    $tryOne[] = $line;
}
```